# Android Open Context Menu Whenever i select any Text anywhere across the device

Tags: android

I am trying to work on one idea. whenever user selects any text anywhere in any `application' on android device` i want to show one option to user just like we get an option for copy.

Is it possible to change `android's` default behavior like this. When user selects any text i want to show one option just like "**copy**" and when user selects that option i want to perform some operation on that selected `text`.

**Any idea how can i achieve this ?**

Comment: by using custom textview you can achieve this

Comment: @RamBabuPudari I highly doubt it. How exactly would you automatically add an option across all parts of the OS and across all apps by making *one* app that contains a custom textview ? Nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to change android's default behavior like this

Not from Android 1.0 through 5.1.

The M Developer Preview offers a means of doing this. Activities supporting the `PROCESS_TEXT` action will show up in the floating action mode that appears when users select text:

[image: Floating Action Mode, Showing Overflow with Custom Apps]

However, as this is not well-documented, it remains to be seen if this will make it into the final edition of Android M.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. Is there any demo project that i can import and see it in action. please dump me the link if you have any. Thanks buddy. This gave me right direction.

Comment: @SachinTrivedi: The API demos available with the M Developer Preview demonstrate this feature.

Comment: Great Thanks. I will upgrade my sdk to have it.